# How do I make Navigation Component Stick to top in Angular

Tags: angular

Injected into my component is a navigation bar. Code is similar to below.

```
<app-shopping-nav ></app-shopping-nav>

<div class="body>
Content goes here
</div>
```

I want the

```
<app-shopping-nav ></app-shopping-nav>
```

injection to stick on top on scroll down.

here's what I have tried:

1. I tried adding class to it
2. I also tried wrapping it around a span with the a class

Here is the css class

```
.stickNav{
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know. Best wishes. :-)

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it so much. I am trying to make it work in my application. It's weird because it's working in stackblitz but not in my app.

Comment: Did you add the css in the style.css file? You can try that it might work.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a solution for you. It seems like a tricky problem. Here is a solution given below =>

```
<app-shopping-nav class="stickNav"></app-shopping-nav>
<div class="body>
Content goes here
</div>
```

It should work. I have made a demo for you in stackblitz. Please check and let me know.
[Working Demo in StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sticky-header-kz1cxr?file=app%2Fapp.component.html).